# How to check which part is using how much memory (RAM)

Tags: sql-server-2008

Currently, I'm using the SQL Server 2008.

2 days ago, the SQL took around 2GB RAM. But now, it takes over 4GB RAM.

I don't know why it worked like that.

I tried to run `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` but I cannot find anything useful.

Did anyone have this problem before. Please advise.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: By design, SQL Server will take RAM as needed, and not release it, up to your MAX Memory setting.